# What are the reasons for kernel taint on OpenWRT 21.02 fresh install on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: kernel

I'm currently running a stock build of OpenWRT 21.02, on a fresh install in Raspberry Pi 4 and I'm getting a tainted kernel error 1024.

Anyone else experiencing this and any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: exactly which image are you using? - and can you show the exact "error"

Comment: @bravo I'm using the 64 bit image, and the error I get is by using cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted. It just lists the value 1024. Any idea why this might have occured? It typically shouldn't happen on a clean image.

Comment: "Any idea why this might have occured(sic)?" because you are using a beta OS with known limitations.

Comment: @milliways I understand that Raspbian may be called a beta OS.  However, OpenWrt has been here for 17 years, and is widely used. May I know how is it still beta OS?

Comment: There is NO 64 bit OS. NOTE Raspbian does not and probably never will have a 64 bit version. Raspberry Pi OS has a 64 bit beta.

Comment: @Milliways Not sure if you read the question completely, but the Pi in this case is running OpenWrt and not Raspbian. You may call Raspbian a beta OS, but I'm referring to OpenWrt. Are you saying that OpenWrt is beta OS or are you referring to Raspbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1024` means you are loading a module from staging - according to [this table at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html#table-for-decoding-tainted-state)

```
Bit Number    Reason that got the kernel tainted
 0       1    proprietary module was loaded
 1       2    module was force loaded
 2       4    kernel running on an out of specification system
 3       8    module was force unloaded
 4      16    processor reported a Machine Check Exception (MCE)
 5      32    bad page referenced or some unexpected page flags
 6      64    taint requested by userspace application
 7     128    kernel died recently, i.e. there was an OOPS or BUG
 8     256    ACPI table overridden by user
 9     512    kernel issued warning
10    1024    staging driver was loaded
11    2048    workaround for bug in platform firmware applied
12    4096    externally-built (“out-of-tree”) module was loaded
13    8192    unsigned module was loaded
14   16384    soft lockup occurred
15   32768    kernel has been live patched
16   65536    auxiliary taint, defined for and used by distros
17  131072    kernel was built with the struct randomization plugin
```

The Pi4 OpenWRT image loads `snd_bcm2835` module - which is from the staging directory

Not sure why OpenWRT would ever need sound - perhaps some package may use it, but the default image does not need sound at all - at least, mine does not

Even though this "taint" isn't at all serious, if you want to remove it, you can delete

```
/etc/modules.d/68-sound-arm-bcm2835
```

And this should remove the "taint"

I've tried it on my OpenWRT Pi 4 and I see no issues with removing that file - nor should there be

Comment: Perfect, this solves it. Thank you!